# How can I create ref cursor array

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want create a stored procedure dynamically define an ref cursor array and then combine this ref cursor array into a single ref cursor and return

something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE types AS 
      TYPE cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
END Types;/

CREATE PROCEDURE P1(DATA OUT types.cursor_type)
IS
BEGIN
     OPEN DATA FOR SELECT COLUMN_A FROM MY_TABLE;
END;/

/***************Here is the procedure that I want to define but I have no idea how to do it *********/
CREATE PROCEDURE P2(MY_OUTPUT OUT types.cursor_type)
IS
    NUM NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO NUM FROM XXX; 

    /*****dynamic create ref cursor array based on NUM (How to define dynamic ref cursor array???)*******/
    REF CURSOR ARRAY my_array[NUM];

    for i in 1... num 
    loop
       P1(my_array[i]);
       i := i+1;
    end loop;

    /**********combine all cursors together into one output ref cursor (How to combine them together into a single output ref cusor???)******/
    MY_OUTPUT := my_array[1] + my_array[2] + ... + my_array[3];
end;/
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: [You can't.](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_variable.htm#LNPLS01312)

Though you can open a ref cursor with a single column of the ref cursor type. For example

```
open outer_cursor for
select O.username,
    cursor(
        select I.*
        from all_objects I
        where I.owner = O.username
    ) as inner_cursor
from all_users O
;
```